# How to find out the status of a Trust and Safety Team ticket?

Tags: discussion

About two-and-a-half weeks ago I received an email from the Trust & Safety team in reply to a ticket I had opened. The email informed me that I should hear from them in the next few days, but that it might take longer to get a response. I haven't heard from anyone in the matter since then. My two messages asking for a followup, sent a week-and-a-half, and a week, ago, respectively, have not been answered. How can I find out the status of my ticket? Also: who are the members of the Trust & Safety team?

UPDATE:

Yesterday, February 9, exactly 1 month after receiving the first email from the Trust & Safety team informing me that I should hear from them in the next few days, I finally received a followup email.

The brief, 3-sentence email, which was signed by a member of the Community Team, rather than the Trust & Safety team like the previous email, did not acknowledge, much less explain, let alone apologize for, the exorbitant amount of time it had taken to follow up on my report. It informed me that my original report would be kept around as reference material, and forwarded to the appropriate team. It didn't clarify which team was deemed the appropriate one. Finally, it stated: "I won't be able to further update you on the results of this report."

Now I understand the meaning of the title "Trust & Safety team": those who turn to this team should *trust* that their report has been taken seriously and acted on, despite the lack of evidence and transparency.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/349266/the-community-teams-stack-exchange-and-how-we-work-together

Comment: Have you got anything back here?

Comment: @JosephWright I'm not sure I understand your question. I haven't received any communication from the Trust & Safety team since posting my original question above.

Comment: @EvanAad That was what I wondered: I will chase as presumably this is important

Comment: @JosephWright Thanks.